# ko.bindingHandlers.if.update function was removed in KnockoutJS 3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, custom-binding

I wrote a `custom binding` that will perform like `if binding` at the first, and work as `visible binding` on the next.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.visibleIf = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
   {
      // Doing stuff here
      // ...

      return ko.bindingHandlers.if.init.apply(this, arguments);
   },
   update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
   {
       // Doing stuff here
       // ...

       ko.bindingHandlers.if.update.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

I used to wrap both of `if.init` and `if.update` and it works fine on `KO 3.0`, I just noticed it was removed on `KO 3.1`.

It is possible to wrap `if.update` function on `KO 3.1` ? or do you have other suggestions that could help to achieve this?

Greatly appreciate it, Thanks.

Comment: You can just remove the `ko.bindingHandlers.if.update.apply(this, arguments);` line and your binding should work fine with KO 3.1.

Comment: Yes, it will work properly after removing the code, but it still will be act the same as a `if binding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property to your wrapper function that tells you if the IF-binding was fired before and/or if it has rendered its childs already. Then you can do exactly the same operations as you would have done with the former update callback.